# Multiple Windows Driver Virtual Serial Port

Tags: wdk

I'm working on a Windows UMDF driver "to map" multiple virtual serial port into one single HW serial port.

I'd like to create a driver that expose to user some virtual COM ports (COM3, COM4, COM5,....) linked to single HW COM port.

I'm able to create driver for single virtual COM (I'm able to create one virtual COM port and link it to HW COM port); now I need to extend my job for several virtual COMs.

How can I generate and expose more virtual COM port in single driver?

Comment: Never have done this before, but the most logical solution is to have multiple virtual COM ports talking with the same HW device. IMO you can't have one driver instance for multiple devices. What is the problem when you add a second virtual COM port with your driver?